# size greater than max_size in containers

Tags: c++

What standard says about situation when size of the container is greater than max_size?

UB, std::bad_alloc or something else?

MSVC throws an exception.

Comment: It depends on what you do. `max_size` is really rather pointless. If you try to add to a container and there isn't enough memory you'll get `bad_alloc`.

Comment: How, precisely, did you get `.size()` to be greater than `.max_size()`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean 'what happens if I try to push the container over `max_size`?' because a container's `size` cannot exceed `max_size`. If it does, then `max_size` returned an incorrect value.

Exactly what happens depends on the container and what operation is attempting to resize the container, but in the case of most re-sizable containers (i.e. `string`, `vector`), the standard requires a `length_error` to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The standard requires a `std::length_error` to be thrown in most cases, but in some cases the allocator may throw a different exception.

From C++03 §21.3/4a (Class template `basic_string`):

> For any string operation, if as a result of the operation, `size()` would exceed `max_size()` then the
>   operation throws `length_error`.

§21.3.3/10-12 (`basic_string` capacity):

> `void reserve(size_type res_arg=0)`;
>   [...]
>   **Throws:** `length_error` if `res_arg > max_size()`.<sup>218)</sup>
>
> 218) `reserve()` uses `Allocator::allocate()` which may throw an appropriate exception.

§23.2.4.2/2-4 (`vector` capacity):

> `void reserve(size_type n)`
>   [...]
>   **Throws:** `length_error` if `n > max_size()`.<sup>248</sup>
>
> 248) `reserve()` uses `Allocator::allocate()` which may throw an appropriate exception.

The standard doesn't explicitly mention this for the other standard containers (`deque`, `list`, `priority_queue`, `map`, `multimap`, `set`, `multiset`, and `bitset`).  However, in Table 65 (Container requirements), it says that `max_size` is the "`size()` of the largest possible container".